# How to cast Any[] to CustomType so that IntelliSense can be used to access the Properties in Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We have one Angular service where we are calling the backend and getting the data and displaying it on UI.

```
export interface UserDataResponse { id: number; userName: string; }

AngularService_Method1() {
    return this.http.get<UserDataResponse[]>(this.appUrl + "/Application/Users")
   }
```

**AngularService_Method1()** is written in Service layer which calls the Backend Users API to get the data. Here we clearly know how the response is. Hence, we are type casting the response as UserDataResponse[].

**In Angular Component**, I can get the Response and I can use this UserDataResponse[] and I can easily get the ***IntelliSense for id & userName properties***.

We have another method in Service layer as **AngularService_Method2()** which returns the Array of Objects.

```
AngularService_Method2(someParameter:String) {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.appUrl + "/Application/someendpoint/" + someParameter)
}
```

and here Response can be of anything any[]. 
It can be anything like below. 
**For Example - Response 1**

```
[{"Id": 1,"Name": "Abc1","City": "Xyz1"},{"Id": 1,"Name": "Abc1","City": "Xyz1"}]
```

**Response 2 -**

```
[{"EmployeeId": 100,"Email": "pqr@pqr.com","Rank": "aa1"},{"EmployeeId": 101,"Email": "xyz@pqr.com","Rank": "aa2"}]
```

**Question is How to cast Any[] to CustomType so that IntelliSense can be used to access the Properties in Angular/Typescript.**

When Response 1 comes I should be able to access the Id,Name,City properties as IntelliSense in my Angular Component.

Comment: Do you know when which response would be sent? i.e. when response1 be sent and when would response2 be sent?

Comment: nope. Its dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

While subscriping give the type

Eg:-

`this.service.method.subscribe((data:Item[])=>//code)`;

Comment: It gets compiled successfully but  Why I am seeing "Cannot find name Item" as warning message.

Comment: replace item with your classname.

Comment: I will update the question and will add more details into it.